# Bitmap animation

Tags: visual-c++, animation, mfc

I'm using Microsoft VC++ and MFC.

Say that I want to create an animation that is composed of N different frames.  Is it more effecient to have a separate CBitmap object for each frame, or to have one big CBitmap that contains the images for all frames, and then index into the big CBitmap when I want to display the next frame in the animation cycle?

Also, can anyone point me to good reference material (online or books) for doing animation using VC++ and/or MFC?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One big bitmap will usually be more efficient.

Offhand, I'm not sure about good books on the subject -- but it's fairly unusual to do animation via GDI, so I wouldn't expect a lot.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I'll look around to see what I can find for related info

Answer (score 1):

For simple animation you can use the MFC CAnimateCtrl object. Only down side is that it requires an AVI as input.

There used to be a freeware utility from Microsoft called VidEdit that could be used to build AVIs.